# SkiaSharp support for color quantization for PNG files

Tags: skia, skiasharp

I'm looking for an all-in-one solution for processing web images

- Resizing
- Cropping
- Save as WEBP / JPEG / PNG
- Drawing simple rectangles
- Adding text
- Reducing colors (quantization) for PNG

The only thing I'm not clear about is PNG quantization. Currently I'm using `pngquant` which works great, but I'd prefer to do everything in one place.

I see the SkiaSharp has [`SKImage.Encode()`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/SkiaSharp.SKImage.Encode/p/SkiaSharp.SKImageEncodeFormat/System.Int32/) which takes a `quality` parameter. However there's no explanation as to what it actually is. Will this give me color quantization for PNG files? If not, is there something else in the library to do this?

Comment: Well from the XML comments `The quality is a suggestion, and not all formats (eg: png) respect or support it.` the quality param seems to be irrelevant for png.  I'm not an expert but I don't think you're going to find much support for png specific operations in skia, AFAIK skia just decodes and encodes png but the in memory usage is usually an RGBA raster bitmap. After decoding you could use [skpaint.filterquality](https://skia.org/user/api/SkPaint_Reference#Filter_Quality_Methods) to draw the image at a lower quality and encode back to png.